# How to have 2 Lambda functions communicate with each other.. when one of them doesn't have Internet access?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

Here's my thing:
I got 2 functions A & B:

- A is in a default Lambda VPC, provided by AWS, that has open internet access
  inbound and outbound
- B is in a specific VPC with a RDS DB, with inbound access but no
  Internet access (no NAT Gateway).

The process is this :

- A sends data to B (via API Gateway) while B inserts that data in a RDS Database
- B is supposed to send confirmation (via another API Gateway) of whether it's okay or not but A keeps getting a 502 error (timeout I guess).

At first I thought it was a stupid Lambda proxy output format error but now I realised it's more serious than that.
I'm looking for some easy/cheap way out (i'm a student on a budget and this is a PoC). Is there some kind of easy solution to this problem?

Comment: Could you change is to that Lambda-A invoke Lambda-B via an `Invoke()` API call, instead of going via API Gateway? It could then pass information back as the return value.

Comment: doesn't the return value require Internet access though?

Comment: The response would come back through the `payload` field in the response to the `Invoke()` API call. Lambda-A would require Internet access, but not Lambda-B. However, Lambda-A will need to wait until Lambda-B is finished, so you're paying for two Lambda functions while Lambda-B is running.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, none of them will have any internet access.

"Placing" function A in a default VPC does not give it internet access nor public IP:. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html).

> Connecting a function to a public subnet **doesn't give it internet access or a public IP address**.

Function A can call  B if it is **not in VPC**. In this case it will have internet access, and will be able to invoke function B directly or call your API gateway endpoint. But it can't be in a public subnet. If you want to place it in a VPC nonetheless, then it should be in private subnet (not public) and you should use private endpoint for API gateway. Such lambda will not be able to invoke public API with NAT gateway.

Function B will be able to invoke your API gateway on condition that you use [private endpoint](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-amazon-api-gateway-private-endpoints/).

Comment: Sorry, I may have been unclear. What I meant is that Function A isn't in one of my VPCs, it has access to the Internet, that's for sure (i've been using for weeks now).
Now, will the private endpoint solution work even if Function A isn't in a VPC?

Comment: @Fares Hi. To use API gateway private endpoint, your function A must be in VPC. Private endpoints are only accessible from a VPC. But function B is already in a private subnet of some VPC. So it should be able to access private endpoint if you place it in same VPC or subnet.

Comment: So the private endpoint must be in the same VPC/Subnet as my Function B, right?

Comment: Yes. More detailed info about about private endpoints is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-private-apis.html).